# Day in Week function - SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am trying to get the day of a week in a SOQL query but the marketingcloud just shows me this error message:

> "Error:'day_in_week' is not a recognized built-in function name."

This is the query I am using in the moment:

```
SELECT
CreatedDate,
Id
FROM Request__c_Salesforce
WHERE day_in_week(CreatedDate)= 2
```

Does anybody know how to solve this error?

Best regards!

Comment: Marketing Cloud uses SQL not SOQL. Can you clarify what you are using and where?

Comment: I am creating a SQL Activity in the automation studio.

In the developer guide, it is said that this language is called SOQL or SOSL. Please do not see this as a provocation. If this term should not be correct, please help me to understand why. 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm

Comment: It's called a SQL activity. That indicates it uses SQL. Of course there is a SOQL Developer Guide but it's not relevant here. We have some frequent MC contributors who can likely help you out.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5  This might be a helpful reference.

Comment: Yeah I am aware that the name SQL Query Activity is a small hint that it is SQL based. 
In the first part of the trailheads section, it is said that salesforce defines a the language of a query that contains a "Select" as SOQL. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/database_basics_dotnet/units/sql_to_soql
But I really do not care about the name. What I cared about, is that people can help me to understand the mistake in my code. 
Nevertheless, I found the answer with your help and searched for "day of the week - sql function". 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The query that is working:

```
SELECT
Id,
DateName(dw,CreatedDate) AS weekday
FROM Request__c_Salesforce
```

Here is a reference for people who are having a similar problem.

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datename.asp

Best regards!

Comment: Saved my life, thank you for discovering this.